# wxStaticBox equivalent for QT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

In wxpython I can use a staticbox in combination with a staticboxsizer to make a box with a title around a widget, like this:

[image: wxstaticbox]

I am fairly new to qt and don't know all the widgets, so maybe I'm missing something trivial, but how can I implement this in pyqt/pyside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called a [QGroupBox](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgroupbox.html):

[image]

You can either create it via a GUI editor (my preferred method), or you can create a `QGroupBox()` object in Python and add it to your window's layout.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, this is exacly what I wanted.  Qt designer is my preferred method too. I have it [integrated with eclipse](http://qt.nokia.com/products/eclipse-integration/) and run [this](http://pastebin.com/gRDkXh9w) script via external tools to make the ui files. It works quite well together.